# Filtro de eventos en FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Estoy trabajando con FullCalendar. Guardo eventos y base de datos con esta estructura:

```
                {
                id: 1,
                title: 'evento',
                nombre: 'Juan',
                start: '2018-09-05',
                end: '2018-09-07'
               },
                {
                id: 2,
                title: 'evento',
                nombre: 'Pepe',
                start: '2018-09-05',
                end: '2018-09-07'
               }
```

y los recibo correctamente de esta forma:

```
  $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
  events: 'http://192.168.1.162/carpeta/eventos.php'
   )}
```

El problema me viene que quiero mostrar solos los eventos que recibo que tengan por ejemplo el nombre de 'Pepe'.

¿Alguna idea para hacerlo?
Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar lo que necesitas, `fullCalendar` tiene un evento que filtra el calendario de acuerdo a una condición o valor, el cual se implementa mediante el evento **[eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender)**; entonces lo que necesitarías sería incluir en tu DOM algún elemento donde puedas filtrar, en este caso un **[select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var list = [
    { 
      id: 1,
      title: 'evento',
      nombre: 'Juan',
      start: '2018-09-05',
      end: '2018-09-07'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'evento',
      nombre: 'Pepe',
      start: '2018-09-05',
      end: '2018-09-07'
    }
  ]
  
  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: list,
    eventRender: function(event, element, view){
      return ['all', event.nombre].indexOf($('#selector').val()) >= 0
    }
  });
  
  $('#selector').on('change',function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <select class="form-control col-md-4 mb-4 mt-4" id="selector">
    <option value="all">Todos</option>
    <option value="Juan">Juan</option>
    <option value="Pepe">Pepe</option>
  </select>
  
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

Destaco que la respuesta se basa en la solución indicada **[acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641355/jquery-fullcalendar-event-filtering)**

Nos comentas colega =)

Comment: Me ha funcionado!! Muchas gracias Paulo.