# FULLCALENDAR (MOSTRAR EVENTOS ESPECIFICOS)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, array

mi problema es que quiero obtener eventos específicos de acuerdo a un valor, y toda la informacion de los eventos se recuperan de la db exitosamente desde un archivo con el siguiente código:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scouts_601_palmira","root","");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Eventos";
$sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
$sentencia -> execute();
$resultado = $sentencia -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

La siguiente ruta del archivo la incluyo en la vista que tiene el fullCalendar listo.

```
events:'http://localhost/MafekingOnline/Sql/ArregloEventos.php',
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que cuando yo le pase un parámetro para comparar si ese evento lo tiene entonces lo pueda mostrar, sino entonces que lo omita
El código seria algo asi:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scouts_601_palmira","root","");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Eventos WHERE Id_rama = :Id_rama";
$sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
$sentencia -> bindParam(':Id_rama', $id_rama, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sentencia -> execute();
$resultado = $sentencia -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Tendría que poner el codigo del archivo donde obtengo la informacion de la base de datos en el mismo que el de fullCalendar para que me reconozca la variable (hasta donde se).

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda para dar con la solución.

Fuentes que he consultado y que podrían dar una pista para la solución a este problema:

[Filtro de eventos en FullCalendar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198361/filtro-de-eventos-en-fullcalendar)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfAgl6CGg2Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y porque no pasas el id por parametro en un GET a tu ruta:

```
events:'http://localhost/MafekingOnline/Sql/ArregloEventos.php?id=5',
```

Y tu **ArregloEventos.php** quedaria:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scouts_601_palmira","root","");
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Eventos".(isset($id) ? " WHERE Id_rama = :Id_rama" : "");
$sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
if(isset($id)){
    $sentencia -> bindParam(':Id_rama', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$sentencia -> execute();
$resultado = $sentencia -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Cuando necesites pasarle a tu ruta otro id puedes tomarlo de tu página, por ejemplo puedes tener un select con los diferentes ids y a la hora de llenar el fullcalendar tomas el valor del option seleccionado, ejemplo:

```
<select id="ids">
  <option value="1">Primero</option>
  <option value="2">Segundo</option>
</select>
```

Antes de inicializar el fullcalendar:

```
var id = document.querySelector("#ids").value;
```

Y ya luego donde esta inicializado:

```
events:`http://localhost/MafekingOnline/Sql/ArregloEventos.php?id=${id}`,
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: Me fue de mucha ayuda. Gracias. Podrias ayudarme con otra que creo es similar a esta?? donde utilizo post y unos select. Gracias nuevamente!!

Comment: creala y dame el link

Comment: Claro. Ya esta, mira: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/202864/select-dinamicos-en-php-y-js-por-el-metodo-post.