# Select dinamicos en php y js por el metodo POST

Tags: php, javascript, formularios, post, html-select

El siguiente código corresponde a la consulta e información obtenida de la DB MySQL:

```
<?php
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scouts_601_palmira","root","");

$Id = $_POST['Id'];

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$Id.'");</script>';

$sql = "SELECT Id, Nombre FROM Especialidades WHERE Id_eje = ':$Id'";
$sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
$sentencia -> bindParam(':$Id', $Id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sentencia -> execute();
$resultado = $sentencia -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.count($resultado).'");</script>';

$opcion = "<option value='0'>Seleccionelo</option>";

while ($especialidades = $resultado) {
$opcion = "<option value='".$fila['Id']."'>".$fila['Nombre']."</option>";
}

echo $opcion;
?>
```

**Este código no devuelve los datos de la consulta.**

Y el siguiente código divido en dos partes es donde están los select que requiero, que sean dinámicos.

Esta primera parte contiene el JavaScript que hace uso del código proporcionado arriba.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#eje-progresion").change(function() {
        //$("#nivel-especialidad").find('option').remove().end().append(
        //  '<option value="Seleccione"></option>').val('Seleccione');

        $("#eje-progresion option:selected").each(function() {
            Id = $(this).val();
            $.post("../Sql/ArregloEspecialidades.php", {Id: Id
            }, function(data){
                $("#especialidad-eje").html(data);
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Este es el código PHP y HTML donde están los select.

```
<form method="POST">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Persona</td>
        <td>Eje</td>
        <td>Especialidad</td>
        <td>Nivel</td>
        <td>Acción</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><select>
            <option></option>
            <?php
            foreach ($personas_rama as $fila) {?>
                <option><?php echo $fila['Primer_nombre']." ".$fila['Segundo_nombre']." ".$fila['Primer_apellido']." ".$fila['Segundo_apellido']; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select></td>
        <td><select id="eje-progresion" name="eje-progresion">
            <option>Selecciona</option>
            <?php
            $ejes = DAOEje :: consultarNombreEjesPorIdProgresion($conexion, $id_cargo_recuperado);
            foreach ($ejes as $eje) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $eje['Id']; ?>"><?php echo $eje['Nombre']; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select></td>
        <td><select id="especialidad-eje" name="especialidad-eje">
        </select></td>
        <td><select id="nivel-especialidad" name="nivel-especialidad">
            <option></option>
        </select></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier contribución que de solución u orientación para resolver este problema.

Comment: Revisa que en tu arreglo $_POST llegue realmente ese id, si no sabes exactamente si lo pasas por GET o POST puedes usar $_REQUEST['id'], siempre y cuando exista ese indice no habra inconvenientes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta modificar tu codigo javascript para que quede de esta manera:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#eje-progresion").change(function() {    
            var opcionSeleccinada = $(this).val();
            if(opcionSeleccinada > 0){
                $.post("../Sql/ArregloEspecialidades.php", {Id: opcionSeleccinada
                }, function(data){
                    $("#especialidad-eje").html(data);
                });
            }
        })
    });
```

Se supone que debas capturar el elemento seleccionado en el evento `onChange` del select y en el caso de que sea diferente al de 'Seleccione un elemento' entonces haces el `$.post` y pasas ese id.

Comment: Vale el código soluciono el error mencionado :), ahora por favor mira la primera parte del código donde hago unas comprobaciones. El primer echo con script me devuelve el Id exitosamente, pero el segundo que comprueba cuantos resultados obtuvo me devuelve 0 y no llena el segundo select; creo que la sentencia sql o el bindParam no lo paso bien

Comment: Tu consulta esta mal a la hora de añadir un parametro es sin comillas y sin el signo de dolar, debe ser: $sql = "SELECT Id, Nombre FROM Especialidades WHERE Id_eje = :Id"; Y a la hora de bindear es: $sentencia -> bindParam(':Id', $Id, PDO::PARAM_INT); Si el id_eje es un entero el 3 parametro de la funcion debe ser PARAM_INT

Comment: Si tienes mas dudas como hacerlo puedes consultar esta url: http://es.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de revisar mi código, si ya di con la solución. Era como decías, donde señalabas los de las comillas.

Comment: El ultimo problema que te mencione estuvo fuera de las ayudas que me proporcionaste (así que me disculpo por ello), pero este nuevo inconveniente que tengo, si esta dentro de esas características. Lo que busco es llenar una tabla HTML con JavaScript (JSON). Por favor si me puedes colaborar te agradezco de antemano. Te paso el enlace??

Comment: Claro no hay problema

Comment: Vale, aqui esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206125/agregar-filas-al-tbody-de-una-tabla-html-con-javascript