# Agregar filas al TBody de una tabla HTML con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, html-tabla

el problema que quiero resolver es poder agregar filas a una tabla con JavaScript, después de haber seleccionado un Input Radio, la tabla debe de cambiar.

El código JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var valor = '';
$("input[name='rama']" ).on('change', function() {
Id = $(this).val();
alert(Id);
    $.post("../Sql/ArregloPersonas.php", {Id: Id
        }, function(data){
            $("#personas-rama").html(data);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Tengo entendido que no puedo hacer el post, debería pasar la variable por el método GET, porque asi como esta, no me reconoce la variable, ya que el archivo que recibe la variable esta en JSON.

El código del archivo JSON es:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scouts_601_palmira","root","");

$idrama = $_POST['Id'];

$sql4 = "SELECT Primer_nombre, Numero_documento, Fecha_nacimiento, Id_cargo FROM Personas";
$sentencia4 = $conexion -> prepare($sql4);
$sentencia4 -> execute();
$personas = $sentencia4 -> fetchAll();

$sql5 = "SELECT Id FROM Cargos WHERE Id_rama =".$idrama."";
$sentencia5 = $conexion -> prepare($sql5);
$sentencia5 -> execute();
$cargos = $sentencia5 -> fetchAll();

for ($i=0; $i < count($personas); $i++) {
for ($j=0; $j < count($cargos); $j++) { 
    if ($personas[$i]['Id_cargo'] == $cargos[$j]['Id']) {
    $integrantes = array();
        array_push($integrantes, $personas[$i]);
    }
  }
}

echo json_encode($integrantes);
?>
```

Aquí es donde no me recibe la variable desde JavaScript, ya que debo pasarla por GET, pero no se como quedaría.

Por ultimo esta el código de la tabla:

```
<table>
<caption>Integrantes</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Numero<br>documento</th>
    <th>Primer<br>nombre</th>
    <th>Segundo<br>Nombre</th>
    <th>Primer<br>apellido</th>
    <th>Segundo<br>apellido</th>
    <th>Inscripción</th>
    <th>Acción</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="personas-rama" name="personas-rama">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier contribución para dar solución a este problema.

Comment: si haces un echo $_POST['id']; te trae algun valor???

Comment: Debes sacar tambien la declaracion de integrantes fuera del ciclo debes inicializarlo antes del primer for

Comment: Si, el echo que hacia me devolvía el valor que le paso por medio de los Input Radio; esa parte esta bien. Ya puse en su lugar la inicialización de la variable integrantes.

Comment: Buen Dariel, gracias por contribuir, por favor tengo un problema con Ajax en este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207501/fullcalendar-no-se-actualiza-automaticamente-al-agregar-un-evento
Avisame si le vas a echar un ojito y de antemano nuevamente gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se podría aplicar la el siguiente código en jquery
una ves que obtengas los datos en json

```
var tr_html="";
$.each(data, function(i,val) {
   tr_html=tr_html+"<tr><td>"+val.Numero_documento+"</td><td>"+val.Primer_nombre+"</td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
});
$("#personas-rama").append(tr_html);//si se requiere remplazar el contenido debera ser html()
```